# How to fix/handle every entry in a tibble list column itself being a list with one entry

Tags: r, tibble

I've been following the ['many models' chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) from the R for data science. I've been able to fit my models and store them as a list column in a tibble. This has been great and makes storing it simpler. The problem seems to be that handling each model entry is a little unwieldy now that I have them in this format. For example:

```
model_table %>%
dplyr::filter(! unlist(map(model_fit, is.null))) %>%
dplyr::mutate("GAIC"            = unlist(purrr::map(model_fit, gamlss::GAIC)),
              "BIC"             = unlist(purrr::map(model_fit, BIC)),
              "AIC"             = unlist(purrr::map(model_fit, AIC)),
              "deviance"        = unlist(purrr::map(model_fit, deviance)),
              "df.residual"     = unlist(purrr::map(model_fit, df.residual)),
              "log. Likelihood" = unlist(purrr::map(model_fit, logLik)),
              "converged"       = unlist(purrr::map(model_fit, function(x) x$converged))) %>%
dplyr::ungroup() %>%
dplyr::mutate("dBIC" = round(BIC - min(BIC), 2),
              "dAIC" = round(AIC - min(AIC), 2)) %>%
dplyr::arrange(dBIC)
```

I'm repeatedly using the function `unlist(purrr::map(..., ...))` which makes me think I'm not doing this correctly.

Is there a more standard or sensible way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried using `map_dbl` etc instead of just plain old `map`? E.g. see the difference in result for `library(tidyverse); tibble(a = 1:5) %>% mutate(square_a = map_dbl(a, ~ . * .))` compared to `tibble(a = 1:5) %>% mutate(square_a = map(a, ~ . * .))`